# Dbeaver / DBVisualizer with Netezza

Tags: jdbc, jar, db2, netezza, dbeaver

Good afternoon,

I'd been searching in a lot of websites (including the official IBM site) trying to find the nzjdbc.jar file, the JDBC driver for Netezza. I need to connect to a Netezza DB in my work, I really enjoy using Dbeaver or DBVisualizer for a better experience but I always have the same message with both db clients.
I really apreciate if someone could share with my the nzjdbc.jar or nzjdbc3.jar file.

[Here's the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSQPW.png)

I'm expecting to find the nzjdbc3.jar file to connect a Netezza database.

Answer (score 0):

You will find Netezza JDBC driver in the Mac CLI package [maccli.package-v11.2.2.9.tar] on IBM FixCentral.  If not already, you'll have to create an IBM ID

[Latest Netezza client packages as of Nov-2023](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/doSelectFixes?options.selectedFixes=11.2.2.9-WS-ICPDS-NPS-Clients-fp25585&continue=1)